# Rails routes /name instead of /users/:id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've completed Hartl's tutorial and am trying to create vanity URLs to my twitter clone in the same way twitter has, e.g. www.twitter.com/realDonaldTrump

I've managed to get my URLs to look like /users/:slug. 
Wondering - how do I get it so it's just /:slug?

Here's what I've done so far:

1.In my User model, there's no column for 'username', so I used 'name' instead.

2.Generated new migration to add a slug column to User model DB.

3.Plugged into rails console to add slugs for all users by typing:

```
User.all.each do |user|
  user.slug = user.name.downcase.parameterize
  user.save
end
```

4.Configured UsersController show action to:

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_slug(params[:id])
  @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  redirect_to root_url and return unless @user.activated?
end
```

Now that I've configured it so it shows /users/:slug, how do I change it so it's just /:slug?

Comment: change the roue to `get '/:id', to: 'users#show'`

Comment: that seems to work, for example, I can visit a profile page /chloe-schamberger. But now I can't visit any other of my pages. I get an error:
undefined method `microposts' for nil:NilClass


      def show
        @user = User.find_by_slug(params[:id])
        @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
        redirect_to root_url and return unless @user.activated?
      end

Comment: It seems that whenever I visit collection pages, like /users, /help, /about, the routes thinks that :id = users. How do I fix this?

Comment: put `get '/:slug', to: 'users#show'` this route at last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ......

**edit app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
end

User.create! name: "Username"
```

**Change User.find to User.friendly.find in your controller**

```
User.friendly.find(params[:id])

rails server

http://localhost:3000/users/username
```

**If you're adding FriendlyId to an existing app and need
to generate slugs for existing users, do this from the
console, runner, or add a Rake task:**

```
User.find_each(&:save)
```

**To get /username instead of /users/username try this ...**

In your User model add

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def to_param
    name
  end
  ...
end
```

But make sure in your controller you then find users by their name.

In your controller add

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def show
    @user = User.find_by(name: params[:id])
  end
end
```

As for routing your users to /username, you have several options:

```
get ':id', to: 'users#show', as: 'show'
resources 'users', path: '/'
```

Just make sure you put these routes at the end of your routes file.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: This requires the friendly ID gem right? Also, I'm trying to get /username instead of /users/username

Comment: @JosephLiu : Yes, this requires `gem 'friendly_id'`

Comment: @JosephLiu : I have updated my answer please have a look. Thanks!

Comment: Should I be updated to_params if I install friendly_id? I thought that was what friendly_id did already

Answer (score 1):

change your root with

```
get '/:slug', to: 'users#show'
```

and on your UsersController

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by slug: params[:slug]
...
end
```

don't forget to remove the ':show' on 
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
of your Controller as "set_user" use :id and not :slug to retrieve instance

beware that you must worry about the slug uniqueness in your model when saving

```
before_validation :set_slug    
validates :slug, uniqueness: true

private

def set_slug
...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`get '/:slug', to: 'users#show'` make this the last route and check.

Since it is the named route we created it should be at the last, so that the other routes are not disturbed.

In your `Users Controller`

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by slug: params[:slug]
end
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with get  '/:slug', but does work with '/:id'. Any reason for this?

Comment: Also, some pages don't seem to work.. for example, my followers page. Is this because I have to replace everywhere that says @user = User.find(params[:id]) with User.find_by_slug(params[:id])?

Comment: Yes.. i could access pages like /users, /about, /contact, but can't access pages like users/example-user/edit, users/example-user/followers

Comment: `get '/:id/edit', to: 'users#edit'` try to change the edit route, at last

Comment: No luck. Says 'Couldn't find User with 'id'=example-user' with this line highlighted: `      @user = User.find(params[:id])`

Comment: have you added slug id to name in User model

Comment: I generated a migration to add column 'slug' to user model DB, then altered User model by adding a def to_param method with slug, and validation with presence for slug